# Android Dagger2 issue. Multiple Retrofit annotations found, only one allowed

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2, dagger

I've found several related topics, but did not fount any suitable solution for my issue. I need to provide two retrofit instance with different base urls. Here's my ApiModule.kt:

```
@AppScope
@Module
internal class ApiModule{

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        var b = OkHttpClient.Builder()

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            b.addInterceptor(logging)
        }
        val t = 60*1000L

        b.readTimeout(t, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        b.writeTimeout(t, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        b.connectTimeout(t, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        return b.build()
    }

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitAdapter(ok: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(ok)
                .baseUrl(Constants.Api.Links.BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }
    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideEnergoApi(r: Retrofit): EnergoApi {
        return r.create(EnergoApi::class.java)
    }

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideEnergoManager(p: PrefHelper, ea: EnergoApi, pm:PayHubManager): DtecManager {
        return DtecManager(p, ea, pm)
    }
}
```

and here's my InfoMudule.kt:

```
@ActivityScope
@Module
internal class InfoModule{

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun provideInfoPresenter(p:PrefHelper, d:DtecManager, pu: PushManager, v:ViewUtil, n:NetworkUtil,
                         a:ApiErrorHandler):InfoPresenter{
         return InfoPresenter(p, d, pu, v, n,a)
    }

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    @Named("Retrofit2")
    fun providePushRetrofitAdapter(ok: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(ok)
                .baseUrl(Constants.Api.Links.BASE_PUSH_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun providePushApi(r: Retrofit): PushApi {
        return r.create(PushApi::class.java)
    }

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun providePushManager(c: Context, p:PrefHelper, pa: PushApi): PushManager {
        return PushManager(c,p,pa)
    }
}
```

My AppComponent:

```
@AppScope
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, ApiModule::class))
internal interface AppComponent{

     fun inject(a:BaseActivity)


     fun createLoginActivityComponent(): LoginComponent
     fun createInfoComponent(): InfoComponent
     fun createPayComponent(): PayComponent
     fun createNfcScanComponent(): NfcScanComponent
     fun createSettingsComponent(): SettingsComponent


     fun getNfcAdapter():NfcAdapter?
}
```

Here's my InfoComponent:

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(InfoModule::class))
internal interface InfoComponent {
     fun injectInfoActivity(a: InfoActivity)
}
```

My PushApi interface:

```
internal interface PushApi {

@POST(Links.Push.subscribe)
fun subscribeToPush(@Header ("Content-type: application/json")
                    @Body b: BodySubscribe): Observable<Response<UniqueKey>>
```

}

My InfoActivity:

```
internal class InfoActivity : BaseActivity(), InfoView, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

@Inject lateinit var presenter: InfoPresenter
@Inject lateinit var viewUtil: ViewUtil

companion object {
    @JvmStatic val PUT_COUNTERS = 101
    @JvmStatic val PAYMENT = 202
    @JvmStatic val NAME = "name"
    @JvmStatic val CURRENT_COUNTER = "currentCounter"
}

private var accountsDialog: AccountsDialog? = null
private var amountDialog: AmountDialog? = null

private lateinit var date: TextView
private lateinit var usedEnergy: TextView
private lateinit var balance: TextView
private lateinit var balanceTitle: TextView
private lateinit var counter1: TextView
private lateinit var counter1Title: TextView
private lateinit var counter2: TextView
private lateinit var counter2Title: TextView
private lateinit var counter3: TextView
private lateinit var counter3Title: TextView
private lateinit var address: TextView
private lateinit var tariff: TextView
private lateinit var refreshView: SwipeRefreshContainer
private var accountsMenuItem: MenuItem? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info)
    val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    date = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_date) as TextView
    usedEnergy = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_used) as TextView
    balance = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_balance) as TextView
    balanceTitle = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_balanceTitle) as TextView
    counter1 = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_counter1) as TextView
    counter1Title = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_counter1Title) as TextView
    counter2 = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_counter2) as TextView
    counter2Title = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_counter2Title) as TextView
    counter3 = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_counter3) as TextView
    counter3Title = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_counter3Title) as TextView
    address = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_address) as TextView
    tariff = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_tv_tariff) as TextView
    refreshView = findViewById(R.id.activityInfo_srl) as SwipeRefreshContainer


    with(refreshView) {
        setOnRefreshListener(this@InfoActivity)
        setColorSchemeColors(ContextCompat.getColor(this@InfoActivity, R.color.colorAccent),
                ContextCompat.getColor(this@InfoActivity, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
    }

    checkComponent(savedInstanceState)
    presenter.attachView(this)

    presenter.subscribeToPush()
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == PUT_COUNTERS && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        updateInfoView()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.info_menu, menu)
    accountsMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_accounts)
    return true
}

override fun onBackPressed() {

}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.action_logout -> presenter.onLogOutClicked()
        R.id.action_accounts -> presenter.onAccountsClicked()
        R.id.action_feedback -> navigator.goToFeedbackView(this, presenter.dtecManager.accountInfo.full_name,
                presenter.dtecManager.accountInfo.abcode)
        R.id.action_settings -> navigator.goToSetingsActivity(this)
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onRefresh() {
    presenter.onUpdateAccount()
}

override fun isSessionActive(): Boolean {
    return checkActiveSession()
}

override fun initComponent() {
    App.instance.createInfoComponent().injectInfoActivity(this)
}

override fun activityIsFinishing() {
    presenter.detachView()
    accountsDialog?.onDestroy()
    amountDialog?.onDestroy()
    App.instance.releaseInfoComponent()
}
}
```

My InfoPresenter:

```
internal class InfoPresenter(
    var prefHelper: PrefHelper,
    val dtecManager: DtecManager,
    val pushManager: PushManager,
    val viewUtils: ViewUtil,
    val networkUtil: NetworkUtil,
    private var apiErrorHandler: ApiErrorHandler
) : BasePresenter<InfoView>(), AccountsDialog.OnAccountDialogListener {

private var context: Context = App.instance.applicationContext
private var stringTokenizer: StringTokenizer? = null

private var getNewAccountInfoSubscription: Subscription? = null
private var uniqueKey: Observable<UniqueKey>? = null
private lateinit var simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat
private lateinit var addressTitle: String
private lateinit var tariffTitle: String
lateinit var accountInfo: AccountInfo
    private set

override fun attachView(mvpView: InfoView) {
    super.attachView(mvpView)
    addressTitle = context.getString(R.string.activityInfo_tv_addressTitle)
    tariffTitle = context.getString(R.string.activityInfo_tv_tariffTitle)
    var locale: Locale
    when (Locale.getDefault().country) {
        "RU" -> locale = Locale("ru")
        else -> locale = Locale("uk")
    }
    simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", locale)
    mvpView.updateInfoView()
}

override fun detachView() {
    super.detachView()
    getNewAccountInfoSubscription?.unsubscribe()
}

override fun onNewAccountSelect(abcode: String?) {
    if (mvpView!!.isSessionActive()) {
        abcode?.let {
            getNewAccountInfo(it)
            mvpView?.showLoadingDialog(true)?.subscribe {
                getNewAccountInfoSubscription?.unsubscribe()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun subscribeToPush() {

    accountInfo = prefHelper.getAccountInfo()
    uniqueKey = pushManager.subscribe(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountInfo.abcode, accountInfo.unitId, Constants.FIREBASE_KEY)

}

fun onUpdateAccount() {
    if (mvpView!!.isSessionActive()) {
        if (networkUtil.isOnline(true)) {
            getNewAccountInfo(dtecManager.accountInfo.abcode)
        } else {
            mvpView?.finishRefreshView()
        }
    }
}

fun onPayClicked(v: View) {
    checkViewAttached()
    viewUtils.freeze(v)
    if (mvpView!!.isSessionActive() && networkUtil.isOnline(true)) {
        mvpView?.showAmountDialog()
    }
}
}
```

When InfoActivity is launched app crashes with error "Multiple Retrofit annotations found, only one allowed". Why doesn't it provide retrofit from InfoModule?

Comment: where are you injecting retrofit ?

Comment: @crgarridos I create modules, then create components which belong either to app or single activity, and then inject activity.

Comment: ok, but in some place you have to declare to request an instance of retrofit to be injected. I guess it could be in the presenter or in a deeper level.

Comment: @crgarridos I don't inject Retrofit instance directly. It's created in activity component, and the component contains a method called injectSomeActivity. The whole flow is: application class creates an application component, then application component creates activity component. The matter is that application module provides general Retrofit instance, while activity module provides another one, but also needs to use the first one, because it makes calls to different APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `qualifiers` so Dagger be able to know which `Retrofit` instance should provide for each case.

1) Create qualifiers

**RetrofitApi.kt**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class RetrofitApi
```

**RetrofitInfo.kt**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class RetrofitInfo
```

2) Use qualifiers

**ApiModule.kt**

```
@AppScope
@Provides
@RetrofitApi
fun provideRetrofitAdapter(ok: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(ok)
            .baseUrl(Constants.Api.Links.BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
}

@AppScope
@Provides
fun provideEnergoApi(@RetrofitApi r: Retrofit): EnergoApi {
    return r.create(EnergoApi::class.java)
}
```

**InfoModule.kt**

```
@ActivityScope
@Provides
@RetrofitInfo
fun providePushRetrofitAdapter(ok: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(ok)
            .baseUrl(Constants.Api.Links.BASE_PUSH_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
}

@ActivityScope
@Provides
fun providePushApi(@RetrofitInfo r: Retrofit): PushApi {
    return r.create(PushApi::class.java)
}
```

Comment: thanks, but got the same error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple Retrofit annotations found, only one allowed. (parameter #1)
        for method PushApi.subscribeToPush".  Added this method to original question

Comment: could you please help with the error mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: Did you follow the steps mentioned in my answer? Did you clean and rebuild your project after follow those steps?

Comment: yes, I followed the steps and cleaned/rebuilt project, but app still crashes with the same error. seems it can't provide the proper retrofit instance to PushApi. I just need to change base url parameter, never thought it would be so difficult to do with dagger.

Comment: in my app, ApiModule is provided to every activity, but I need also to  provide InfoModule to InfoActivity. Therefore, two instances of Retrofit are provided to InfoActivity. May it be the case of the error?

Comment: Now, I need to see you InfoPresenter related code, could you added it? InfoPresenter implementation as well as InfoPresenter provider class

Comment: I added code of InfoPresenter to original post. InfoPresenter is provided in InfoModule class